# -Last view page in website-

Tags: asp.net

is it possible to display all the pages that user have visited?For example, my website have some category(shoes,shirt,bag), I want to display the pages the user have visited & display the pages for the user to see.

Comment: You mean on your website, or all pages he's visited since opening his browser, or all pages in his history, or all pages ever?

Comment: We'll need a little more information to be able to answer this question. Do you mean all the pages that user has ever visited? Or do you mean in just this one visit? Do you want to do it on the server side? On the client side? What purpose are you looking to implement this? For breadcrumbs, for some sort of tracking or analytics? Do you want to display the page to the user themselves, or do you want the data for yourself?

Comment: Is in my website,actually I wanted to tracked on certain the user enter and display it n the website itself. To show the user the pages he/she have entered.

Comment: This is the Internet we're talking about.  Anything is possible.

Comment: oh, but I only could find how to display last view pages. Any suggeston?...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a Referer stack. Or if you are interested in categories or products rather than actual pages, a stack of those.